# addView not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

My code for adding a view is :

```
LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
LL.removeAllViewsInLayout(); //Works fine, is necessary for a separate reason
tx = new TextView(this);
tx.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LL.addView(tx); //Program fails
```

The program stops at the addView function.

Comment: May we have a stacktrace?

Comment: If tx is a TextView, why are you trying to access via index?

Comment: @ashishduh That was a copying mistake, corrected it.

Comment: This question is off topic because the op lacks minimal OOP knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. I was calling the the above function(of MainActivity) through an AsyncTask class(by a listener) and rather than calling in OnPostExecute I was calling at end of doInBackground.

Comment: Yes, adding a layout must be done on the UI Thread, so OnPostExecute is where you want it. In the future, if you include a bigger snippet of code and/or your error log/stacktrace, we'll be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

"tx" is not an array, so you can't access tx[i]. You want LL.addView(tx);

Comment: That was due to copying mistake, I have now corrected it.

Comment: Provide the stacktrace for more help.